# Wrong reference path to Mail.php

Tags: php, email, pear

Having troubles sending email throw php on centos 6.7 with cpanel installed.
I assume the problem with Mail.php reference path but I don't know how to correct it. The mail.php file located here: /home/userfolder/php/Mail.php (I have installed the following PEAR packages: Auth_SASL, Mail, Net_SMTP, Net_Socket)
The error which I get is:
**Fatal error: Class 'Mail' not found in home/userfolder/public_html/_sendmail.php on line 14**

```
<?php
ini_set("include_path", '/home/userfolder/php:' . ini_get("include_path") );

$from = "Sandra Sender <info@domain.com>";
$to = "Ramona Recipient <info@domain.com>";
$subject = "Email";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
$host = "mail.domain.com";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$headers = array ('From' => $from,   'To' => $to,   'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',   array ('host' => $host,     'auth' => true,     'username' => $username,     'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) 
    {   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>"); 
    } else
    {   
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");  
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add into begin of file

```
require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/Mail.php';
```

Comment: Thanks, almost worked, was needed to add 'php' folder name:
require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/php/Mail.php';